# How to make an object emit light that also iluminates other objects?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting, color

I have multiple problems. I wan the wing to emit light. But it doesn't iluminate the body at all. Also is there a way to make the colours visable when it emits light (or only make the parts that aren't black emit light)? 
[image]